# Does localStorage or sessionStorage affect Website accessibility?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, accessibility, session-storage

I would like to use localStorage/sessionStorage to store essential information during a commerce process, which includes site reloads/redirects. Forms are not an option.

That implies, that the user has to have JavaScript enabled. That fact and the usage of these techniques, could it affect accessibility tools, for instance screen readers?

I could not found any information in the [WAI-ARIA specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1).

Comment: SessionStorage and LocalStorage are places to store persistent data available exclusively to JavaScript side, the former option beeing Cookie, they have nothing to do with ARIA or with the DOM.

Comment: I was wondering, if accessibility devices/tools provide such functionality at all.

Comment: My educated guess is: NO ... they don't read the local/session storage. ARIA is applied and interpreted to/from the HTML elements mostly with the `role`, `tabindex` and `aria-*` attributes. Ex:  <span role="button">A Button</span>

Comment: On which sources is your guess based? :) If they don't read local/session storage, my site would not be usable, isn't that right?

Comment: Accessibility has nothing to do with data persistence

Comment: My source is the single point of truth regarding aria in the browser:  https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/

Comment: @Dummy: If one needs a screen reader and my site uses techniques, which the reader does not support, the site is not accessible for him.

Comment: Yes it would be if you make it to do so. From javascript side you read from local storage and apply the aria annotations to the elements.

Comment: True, that just means the APIs are not supported, like async/await is not supported in older browser, if that's the case, it is hard to work around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no longer considered as being a problem.

This is documented in the WCAG FAQ : [Can I meet WCAG 2.0 with Javascript/Ajax, Flash, PDF, Silverlight, and other technologies?](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/wcag2faq#othertechs)

More information can be read in the [conformance claim chapter](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/conformance.html)

Javascript is considered nowadays as being "Accessibility Supported" but you would have to explicity state that this technology is "relied upon" in any conformance claim you may establish.

Comment: I accept Adams answer, because of the WCAG and UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20 links. Thats enough for me to trust, that devices/software supporting such standards can handle session-/localStorage in JavaScript. Thanks also to Dummy and Tiberiu C. for the hints and helpful discussion.